# Prove that solution of following equations are integer

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

> > If $a$ and $b$ are integers and solutions of equation $y-2x-a=0$ and $y^2-xy+x^2-b=0$ are rational, then prove that the solutions are integers.

**My Approach**:

$y=2x+a$ and I put $y=2x+a$ in second equation from that i obtained a result $3x^2+3xa+(a^2-b)=0$

Then i considered the roots of above equations $\alpha$ and $\beta$

so sum of roots = $\alpha+\beta=-a$ and products of roots $\alpha\cdot\beta=\frac{(a^2-b)}{3}$

Now i can clearly see that roots are rations but cannot prove  that roots are integer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a rational solution $x=p/q$ where $p, q$ are co-prime and we can take $q >0$ without loss of generality.  Then $p/q$ satisfies
$$
3\left(\frac{p}{q}\right)^2+3\left(\frac{p}{q}\right)a+(a^2-b)=0.
$$
Multiply by $q^2$ to give you
$$
3p^2 +3pqa+(a^2-b)q^2=0.$$
Now $q$ divides the middle and right hand term so $q$ divides $3p^2$.  But $p$ and $q$ are relatively prime, which means $p$ and $q^2$ are also relatively prime and therefore by Euclid's lemma $q$ must divide $3$.  Accordingly $q=1$ or $3$.

If $q=3$, the quadratic becomes
$$
\frac{p^2}{3}+ap+(a^2-b) = 0
$$
implying $p^2/3$ is an integer and so $3$ now divides $p$ which contradicts the requirement $p$ is co-prime to $q = 3$.  Thus $q \neq 3$ and so $q=1$.  Thus, $x$ is an integer and so is $y$.

Answer (score 1):

Write the whole formula out: $$x={-3a\pm\sqrt{12b-3a^2}\over 6}$$

The whole thing is rational, and $a,b$ are integers, means $12b-3a^2=c^2$ for some integer $c$.

First, it's easy to see $c$ is a multiple of $3$ because the left side is a multiple of $3$.

(1) If $a$ is odd, then $12b-3a^2$ is odd so $c$ is odd.

(2) If $a$ is even, then $12b-3a^2$ is even so $c$ is even.

Therefore $a$ and $c$ always has same parity and $-3a\pm c$ is always even and hence is a multiple of $6 \implies x$ is integer. $y$ is therefore integer from the first original equation.

Answer (score 1):

$y-2x=a$   $\Rightarrow  y^{2}-4xy+4y^{2}=a^{2}$

$4b=4y^{2}-4xy+4x^{2}$

Subtracting will give, $3y^{2}=4b-a^{2}$.

$y$ can't have any integer apart from $1$ as a denominator, hence $y$ is an integer. Write down the formula for quadratic formula for $x$ and then apply this and the answer will follow.